# Where did "-?>" go?

Tags: clojure, macros

I am looking for "-?>", which works identically to "->" unless one of the threaded functions returns nil. If nil is ever encountered in the threading process, the return value of the threading expression is nil. Useful.

Here is where I am finding mention of this thing.
http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/clojure.contrib.core/-_q%3E

*from above site*

```
Same as clojure.core/-> but returns nil as soon as the threaded value is nil itself (thus short-circuiting any pending computation).
Examples :
(-?> "foo" .toUpperCase (.substring 1)) returns "OO"
(-?> nil .toUpperCase (.substring 1)) returns nil
```

I am on clojure 1.4.

What/where/how do I get access to this functionality? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*Where did `clojure.contrib` go?*](http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Where+Did+Clojure.Contrib+Go) lists that `clojure.contrib.core` was (partially) migrated to [`clojure.core.incubator`](https://github.com/clojure/core.incubator). This includes the old `-?>` macro.